# Wordpress Drop Down Menu on Mobile Not Responding / Working

Tags: css, iphone, wordpress, mobile, drop-down-menu

Im hoping someone can help me solve this issue. I have started using wordpress finally instead of coding everything and I am stuck on the drop down menu right. the site is newsby2.com everything looks great and how i want on my laptop and the menu is not a drop down on the laptop but when i go to mobile it look like its supposed to be a drop down but its not responding. The word Menu appears in red and when i click on it it changes to white color but nothin comes down. Ive tried putting Inline on some of the codes but what that did is it just displayed the submenu right away without me having to click on it. What i want to do is when i click on the word menu for the sub menu to appear.

```
/*--------------Mobile Menu-------------------*/
#mobile-menu {
display:none;
position:relative;
margin:0 15px;
}
#mobile-menu > span {
display:inline-block;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family:'Rokkitt', serif;
font-size:24px;
cursor:pointer;
color:#e03d3d;
}
#mobile-menu > span:hover {
color:#fff;

}
#toggle-view-menu {
display:none;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
border-top: none;
position:absolute;
top:33px;
left:0;
z-index:99999;
width:220px;
}
#toggle-view-menu > li {
margin: 0;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
list-style: none;
background-color:#e03d3d;
border-top:1px solid #fff;

}
#toggle-view-menu > li:first-child {
border-top:none;
}
#toggle-view-menu h3 {
font-size: 18px;
margin: 0;  
float: left;
line-height: 40px;  
padding: 0 15px;
}
#toggle-view-menu h3 a {
color: #fff;
width:100%;
display:block;
}
#toggle-view-menu li:hover {
background-color: #c72f2f;
}
#toggle-view-menu span {
float: right;
font-size: 26px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
line-height: 40px;
background-color:#c72f2f;
}
#toggle-view-menu li.active {
background-color:#c72f2f;
}
#toggle-view-menu li.active span,
#toggle-view-menu li.active h3 a {
color:#fff;
}
#toggle-view-menu .menu-panel {
margin: 0px;
display: none;
padding: 10px 15px 0;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
background-color:#c72f2f;
border-top:1px solid #fff;
}
#toggle-view-menu .menu-panel ul {
margin:0;
}
#toggle-view-menu li .menu-panel ul li {
border:none;
list-style:disc inside;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
color:#fff;
}
#toggle-view-menu .menu-panel ul li a {
display:inline-block;
*display:inline;
zoom:1;
color:#fff;
font-size:12px;
}
#toggle-view-menu .menu-panel ul li ul {
margin-left:40px;
margin-top:10px;
}

#main-content {
padding:25px;
background-color:#fff;
}

/* =========================================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add some jQuery to detect clicking the text.

```
jQuery("#mobile-menu > span").click(function() {
    jQuery("#toggle-view-menu").slideToggle(500);
    return false;
});
```

Feel free to edit the 500 to control the speed.

More info on [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: Hi Aaron, where would i need to put that code exactly? sorry i only saw your answer now.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I just tried putting that code into my custom.js file under the mobile section but it doesnt seem to do anything it just does the same thing as before:S...

Comment: Hi @Essentialz, try removing the code within the mobile section (save it somewhere) and add only that, but inside:

`jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    **code here**
});`

The code I posted works for me when pasted into console.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function () {  
    jQuery("#mobile-menu > span").click(function() {
    jQuery("#toggle-view-menu").slideToggle(100);
    return false;
    });
  
         
    });

Comment: i tried that code but it doesnt do anything on my end unless im missing something:S @aaron

Comment: and i tried with 500 for toggle originally as well..im so lost as to why this is so hard are you sure its nothing to do with the css somewhere?:S

Comment: Try putting it in again, but without the jQuery(document).ready().. code as Edgar suggested. 

Seems to only work when I do that. 

So for the mobile menu section simply have:

`jQuery("#mobile-menu > span").click(function() {
    jQuery("#toggle-view-menu").slideToggle(500);
    return false;
});`

Hope that fixes it for you.

Answer (score -1):

The CSS looks good, it seems to be an error in your `custom.js` file.

The mobile menu function seems to work fine but not when wrapped by the

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {});
```

You can try removing the document ready function by removing the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {" in line 163,
and "}); in line 197
```

Comment: This should be the location of the file:
wp-content/themes/news-mix-light/js/custom.js

Comment: Hi Edgar, I have found the custom.js file and that line of code but when i remove it, it doesnt do anything. it still acts the same as before :S....

Comment: Make sure the modification you made is reflected on the browser by opening the file http://www.newsby2.com/wp-content/themes/news-mix-light/js/custom.js

You might need to clear your browser's cache, and sometimes wordpress themes have a cache folder that needs to be emptied.

I hope this solves the issue.

Comment: hi Edgar, i tried clearing my iphone safari history turning off the phone and back on and then going into browser cache on wordpress and selecting prevent caching of objects after settings change but it does nothing. its still the same as before where it shows menu in red and when i click on it menu turns to white which it should but no sub menu appears

Comment: You are right, the file still looks the same (i can see it here: http://www.newsby2.com/wp-content/themes/news-mix-light/js/custom.js). Your WP theme might have a cache folder that needs to be emptied (not sure how, it depends on your theme).

P.S. Also, instead of looking at your phone, you can resize the browser window in your computer to replicate the phone width (i think this way is easier to troubleshoot).

Comment: hi Edgar, ive figured out how to clear all caches, which i did and it still did nothing just the same thing. then i tried what Aaron suggested uptop as well and nothing happened:S...this is maddening.